# ruby/rails strip out xml code based on regex expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I receive the following xml in a database field.

```
<Request type="Final">
    <Field name="Grade">94.5</Field>
    <Field name="EmployeeName">2398;;;Mike5</Field>
    <Field name="Date">051215</Field>
</Request>
```

Currently, I just receive it and display them as it is:

```
  def request_xml
    (request.blank? ? "" : request.message)
  end
```

Now, I want to return the xml by stripping of the EmployeeName value to nil i.e  2398;;;Mike5 from 2398;;;Mike5 based on certain logic

So I am ok with 2 solutions

```
>  1. if EmployeeName value matches a regex, return null else return the value as it is?
>  - Return <Field name="EmployeeName"></Field>
>  2. if EmployeeName value matches a regex completely strip out the whole EmployeeName XML: <Field
> name="EmployeeName">2398;;;Mike5</Field> from the result
```

Is either of the above solution possible via ruby/rails code?

Comment: What removal logic do you mean? The answer depends on it.

Comment: Thanks.what would be thd code to search for the EmployeName value. `regex.match(<Value of EmployeeName Field>) ? "":  xml.css('Field[name=EmployeeName]').map(&:remove)`

Comment: I've updated the code, does it solve your problem now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @asiniy already answered, you can use `nokogiri` for changing your xml, like this:

**UPDATE**: you can filter tag contents with the following code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML('<Request type="Final">
    <Field name="Grade">94.5</Field>
    <Field name="EmployeeName">2398;;;Mike5</Field>
    <Field name="Date">051215</Field>
</Request>')

# remove all Employee elements, containing text 2398
xml.css('Field[name=EmployeeName]').select { |node| node.text =~ /2398/ }.map(&:remove) 

puts xml
```

will output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Request type="Final">
    <Field name="Grade">94.5</Field>

    <Field name="Date">051215</Field>
</Request>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through [nokogiri gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri). Here is [official tutorial](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = Nokogiri::XML('<Request type="Final">
    <Field name="Grade">94.5</Field>
    <Field name="EmployeeName">2398;;;Mike5</Field>
    <Field name="Date">051215</Field>
</Request>')

if xml.xpath('//EmployeeName')
  do_whatever_you_want
```